# Failed to resolve type for directive processor T4Toolbox.VolatileAssemblyProcessor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, t4

I'm trying to use types from my own project in a T4 template, and so I want to use the VolatileAssembly directive so I don't have to keep restarting Visual Studio:

```
<#@ VolatileAssembly processor="T4Toolbox.VolatileAssemblyProcessor" name="C:\Josh\Archimetrics\Archimetrics.Consulting\Suntex\SuntexFirstInMathTools\bin\Debug\SuntexFirstInMathTools.exe" #>
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
A processor named 'T4Toolbox.VolatileAssemblyProcessor' could not be found for the directive named 'VolatileAssembly'. The transformation will not be run.  
The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to resolve type for directive processor
T4Toolbox.VolatileAssemblyProcessor.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(String processorName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessCustomDirectives(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session, IEnumerable`1 directivesToBeProcessed)
```

I've installed the T4 toolbox and restarted, but for some reason it will not recognize the VolatileAssemblyProcessor.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

> They are also harder to use than templates because code they generate
>   is invisible to you by default. In addition, the VolatileAssembly is
>   no longer necessary because in Visual Studio 2012 the assembly
>   directive shadow-copies the assembly files before loading them
>   - [the developers page](http://www.olegsych.com/2012/12/t4-toolbox-for-visual-studio-2012/) -

So I think you do not need this directive anymore. Only use `<#@ assembly name="YourPathOrName" #>` will fix your problem.